# How to implement custom hover for the IMarker in Eclipse plugin development？

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hover

In Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14.0), plugin development was carried out and an IMarker type was customized, defined as follows (plugin.xml):

```xml
 <extension  
      id="my.markerType"  
      name="My Marker"  
      point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">  
   <persistent  
         value="true">  
   </persistent>  
   <super  
         type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker">  
   </super>  
 </extension>
```

How to customize the display content for mouse hover，

I hope to implement a Java error prompt similar function when editing txt text, display error messages, and provide code completion suggestions。

Comment: Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification` extension point and all the org.eclipse.jdt.ui.xxxx` extension points.

Comment: if class implements ITextHover, ITextHoverExtension, ITextHoverExtension2, How to declare plugin.xml and which extension point to use?   I asked GPT and the answer I got was to use  ‘org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextHover‘, ‘org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.ITextHoverExtension’，‘org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.ITextEditorHover’ or 'org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextHover', but prompt Unknown extension point.

Comment: search in https://help.eclipse.org, not found this extension point.

Comment: All those things are Java Interfaces that your code will have to implement. For the Java editor look at the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers` extension point. ChatGPT is going to be pretty useless for complex technical stuff like this because it won't have been trained on much information about this.

Comment: thanks!  If I want to apply this prompt to a txt file, are there any relevant extension points that I can use?

Comment: I don't think the basic text editor supports any hover extension points. It has the basic support code but you would have to write a new editor extending it to actually support the hovers (which is what the Java editor does).